# Dynamically and efficiently assigning today's date as string to property

Tags: javascript

As the title says I want to dynamically assign today's date as string in "DD/MM/YYYY" format to the property. It has to be dynamically calculated and assigned right next to the objects property declaration.

I figured something like this:

```
var obj = {
    today: `${(new Date).getDate()}/${(new Date).getMonth()}/${(new Date).getFullYear()}`
};
```

Which works perfect BUT it's obviously not efficient as it creates three new Date instances.
I would like to do it something like this:

```
var obj = {
    today: (
        const today = new Date;
        return `${today.getDate()}/${today.getMonth()}/${today.getFullYear()}`
    )
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current formatted date dd/mm/yyyy in Javascript and append it to an input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409299/how-to-get-current-formatted-date-dd-mm-yyyy-in-javascript-and-append-it-to-an-i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is an **[IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)** (Immediately Invoked Function Expression): basically, you want to wrap the entire generator function and invoke it immediately when the object is defined:

```js
var obj = {
    today: (() => {
        const today = new Date;
        return `${today.getDate()}/${today.getMonth()}/${today.getFullYear()}`
    })()
};

console.log(obj);
```

On a side note:

- You should be doing `+1` on `today.getMonth()`, because the method [returns a zero-based index of the month](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)
- You might want to use [`.padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) to force double-digit months and date.

See updated example here:

```js
function pad(val) {
  return val.toString().padStart(2, '0');
}

var obj = {
    today: (() => {
        const today = new Date;
        return `${pad(today.getDate())}/${pad(today.getMonth() + 1)}/${today.getFullYear()}`
    })()
};

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var today = new Date();
var obj = {
 today:(
   return `${today.getDate()}/{today.getMonth()}/${today.getFullYear()}`
)
}
```

should be work