# How to convert this type of date time format to readable string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I get a datetime value from api in this format: `2022-11-11T08:52:01.000000Z` I need to convert it to readable form with javascript.

I need this in any readable form, both time and date should be included

Comment: provide a sample output you need

Comment: need it in this format: DD MM YY Time

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: do you want use third party library? If not, please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/12409344/12040727

Comment: can you please try  dateTimevariable.toLocaleDateString();

Comment: yes, i was using moment but its formatting it wrong way

Comment: let me try.....

Comment: _"i was using moment"_ Why don't you include the code you were using and explain why it wasn't working?

Comment: @NasyxNadeem please edit your topic with your example.

Comment: Try using dayjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
import moment from "moment"

const time = "2022-11-11T08:52:01.000000Z"
const formattedDate = moment(time, "DD/MM/YYYY")
console.log(formattedDate)
```

More information: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the date-fns library:

https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/format

Easy way of converting dates to any format you desire.

`warning: pseudo code`

```
import {format} from 'date-fns'

const date = 2022-11-11T08:52:01.000000Z
const formatedDate = format(date, DD MM YY hh:mm)
```

Comment: Error: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/tanesco-tanzania/screens/TaskDetails.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (47:51)                                                                          <Text style={styles.date}>{format(date, DD MM YY hh:mm)}</Text>

Comment: 1. Have you installed the date-fns library?
2. Did you import `format` from said library?
3. Did you read the docs regarding how to format the date?

Answer (score 1):

you need to install the the following package

npm install moment or yarn add moment

or you can use

npm install dayjs or yarn add dayjs

then after format your time as the following

if you choose to use moment do this

```
import moment from 'moment';
moment('2022-11-11T08:52:01.000000Z').format("DD/MM/YY")
```

and if you choose to use dayjs use

```
 import dayjs from "dayjs";
 dayjs('2022-11-11T08:52:01.000000Z').format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss")
```

for more info go to their official documentation [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/)
and [for dayjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs)