# How to convert dd/MM/yyyy into dd/mm/yyyy in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, simpledateformat

I have a date field on which I am calling datepicker in the following format :

```
$(function() {
      $('.dob').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy',

      });
});
```

When the user selects the date, I am getting, say,

```
02 March 2002
```

I want to display this date in above format only but save as dd/mm/yyyy i.e .

```
02/03/2002
```

How to convert my String dd/MM/yyyy to String dd/mm/yyyy?
Have tried with simpledateformat, also by providing locale arguments, none of these worked.

Comment: Please be aware that JavaScript is not Java. What are you looking for? You've put Java in the title, given JavaScript code, and tagged both.

Comment: No, I want to display month name which is why I have taken MM but want to convert it to 03 before saving in db.

Comment: Please take care with adding tags. You have a tag there that is unrelated to javascript, and there are no tags that indicate which library and widget you are using.

Comment: `MM` = `03`, `MMM` = `Mar`,  `mm` = minutes - in *most* sensible date/time formatting conventions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show the date as `02 March 2002`, you should change the dateFormat to the following:

```
dateFormat: 'dd MM yy'
```

All the formatting options for the jQuery DatePicker can be found [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate).

It is not recommended to save the date as a string but rather the corresponding date object supported by the database. If you still wish to get the date as `dd/mm/yyyy`, it could be done like this:

```
let dateAsString;
$(function() {
  $('.dob').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        onSelect: function() {
            let dateObj = $(this).datepicker('getDate') // Retrieves the selected date
            let yy = dateObj.getFullYear()
            let mm = dateObj.getMonth() + 1 // Month starts at 0
            if (mm < 10) mm = '0' + mm
            let dd = dateObj.getDate()
            if (dd < 10) dd = '0' + dd

            dateAsString = dd + '/' + mm '/' + yy
        }
  });
});
```

`dateAsString` will be the string you are looking for.

The formatting idea is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12409344/14803527).

Comment: That would result in user input display as '02/03/2002' but I want to show it as 02 March 2002 and then convert March into integer before saving in db.

Comment: I find it quite disturbing that you updated your answer with the information I had put in my answer, even using the same locale argument. If you decide to reuse information from another answer, then the least you can do is add an attribution.

Comment: @trincot I didn't mean to use anything from your answer, I'm pretty sure that at around the time I updated my answer after seeing the comment, that you posted yours. And yes I did copy the locale argument from you after seeing your answer, as I thought it is a better alternative than what I had before. I'll update my answer with what I previously used, as I don't think it's fair that I use something from your answer. My bad.

Comment: Well my answer which came 10 minutes before your update is of no more use now. I have deleted it.