# javascript - Get the time out of my browser

Tags: javascript, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get current date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript)

How can i Get the time out of my browser whit using javascript?
This do I need to make a comparison in my script.

Comment: Do you want to get the client's system time using javascript? and compare it to some other value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
currentTime = new Date();
time = currentTime.getTime();
hours = currentTime.getHours();
```

etc

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to get the current time:

```
var currentTime = new Date();
```