# Delay running a function for 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I'm looking to delay running this function for 3 seconds:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#FormsPageID table tr:nth-child(12) td:nth-child(2) div span span input')
  .on('focus', function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      if($this.val() == '4/11/2013'){
          $this.val('');
      }
  })
  .on('blur', function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      if($this.val() == ''){
          $this.val('4/11/2013');
      }
  });
</script>
```

The examples I've come across all involve using setTimeout to or show an element after X seconds. But I'm unsure how that would apply to my function.

Comment: what do you want to delay? the part where you bind the events, or do you want to delay the body of the events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use setTimeout :

```
setTimeout(function(){$('#FormsPageID table tr:nth-child(12) td:nth-child(2) div span span input')
 .on('focus', function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      if($this.val() == '4/11/2013'){
          $this.val('');
      }
  })
  .on('blur', function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      if($this.val() == ''){
          $this.val('4/11/2013');
      }
  });}, 3000);
```

Comment: thanks, gabitzish! worked perfectly. if i wanted to use the current date for the value instead of 4/11/2013, how would i modify this to do so?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) as it is fired once on the other hand [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) is triggered until clear interval is called.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sWrjE/)**

```
$('#FormsPageID table tr:nth-child(12) td:nth-child(2) div span span input')
   .on('focus', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.val() == '4/11/2013'){
       setTimeout(function(){ 
             $this.val('4/11/2013');
       }, 3000); 
     }
}).on('blur', function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      if($this.val() == ''){
          setTimeout(function(){ 
             $this.val('4/11/2013');
          }, 3000); 
      }
});
```

**setTimeout**

> The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression
>   after a specified number of milliseconds.

**setInterval**

> The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression
>   at specified intervals (in milliseconds).
>
> The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until
>   clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed.

Comment: that doesn't work for me. to clarify, i'm looking to run this 3 seconds after the page has loaded - once loaded, the onfocus and onblur don't need any sort of delay. would wrapping all of my original code in a setTimeout function do the trick?

Comment: There was typo, setTimout should be setTimeout, check my updated answer with live demo.

Comment: if i wanted to use the current date for the value instead of 4/11/2013, how would i modify this to do so?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has its own .delay() function.
For documentation: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Although I'm not able to test this for myself atm. This might give you a small idea how to accomplish this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#FormsPageID table tr:nth-child(12) td:nth-child(2) div span span input').delay(3000).focus(function () { 
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.val() == '4/11/2013'){
        $this.val('');
    }
  }).delay(3000).blur(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.val() == ''){
        $this.val('4/11/2013');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: if i wanted to use the current date for the value instead of 4/11/2013, how would i modify this to do so?

Comment: @manh2244 Sorry for my late reaction. In this topic you can preview how to retrieve the current date http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript Simply construct the date and put it into a var which you will use instead of the '4/11/2013' string.