# Switching a function value to current date instead of an exact date

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

How would I modify the function below to assign a value of whatever the current date is instead of 4/11/2013?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#FormsPageID table tr:nth-child(12) td:nth-child(2) div span span input')
  .on('focus', function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      if($this.val() == '4/11/2013'){
          $this.val('');
      }
  })
  .on('blur', function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      if($this.val() == ''){
          $this.val('4/11/2013');
      }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: click this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off Parthik's answer, you can make that a function, call it inside the .val()

```
function getCurrentDate() {
    var date = new Date();
    var strDate = (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" +date.getFullYear()
    return strDate;
}
```

And in your code, change:

```
$this.val('4/11/2013');
```

To

```
$this.val(getCurrentDate());
```

Comment: Just to be sure, where would I place this function within my existing code?

Comment: Inside the if statement in the `.on` function.

Answer (score 1):

This would work

```
var date = new Date();
var strDate = (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" +date.getFullYear()
```