# JQuery Mobile DateTime set to current

Tags: jquery, datetime, jquery-mobile

Hi there I am using JQuery mobile to create a small app. For a part of the app I want to display the date and time to the user and them be unable to edit this. Currently I just have this:

```
div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br">Date:<br>
  <input type="datetime-local" name="date" id="date" value="" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
</div>
```

I want to set this to the current date and time instead of the user being able to select for themselves. I have had a search but don't seem to be able to find much. I would really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Why use an input control then? Why not a span? You could use a disabled input control but it won't look as good. You'll have to either generate the value on the server or in script.

Comment: Thats the thing I want it to look good. Are there any tutorials etc... that you could point me in the direction of? Thanks

Comment: [Creating a JS Clock](http://www.elated.com/articles/creating-a-javascript-clock/)
Also checkout Date.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Rup mentioned, you should rather use a span eg than an input element, if the date is just displayed. input makes no sense if nothing is meant to be "put in" (semantics..). You could generate the current Date with javascript simply using the Date() object and then append it to your (span)element. Maybe you'll find this answer helpful: [javascript date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript)

Comment: I hate it when people ask something and are answered something else. How would you set the datetime to an input to today or let's say a certain date? I need the same thing as OP but I actually need to display the stuff.