# how to get current day, month and year in number format

Tags: jquery

i am making a ajax/jquery online app and I need a bit of help, i am storing the current day, month and year being used as global varibles, when the program starts at first the dates will be set to today's date, so my questions are pretty simple and are as follows:

''

3 simple j Query questions:

1) how do i get the current day in this format: 00

2) how do i get the current month in this format: 00

3) how do i get the current year in this format: 0000

Comment: Perhaps google could help you rather than asking people to give you code. It's very easy to find this answer.

Comment: are you using jQuery or javascript native date

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get current date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Whaat have you already tried, show us some code. (Seriously i am going to macro this, how many times i've posted it by now...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this: [Today's date](http://jsfiddle.net/Somnath_k/UuvRk/)

```
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd < 10){
      dd='0'+dd;
    }
    if(mm < 10){
       mm="0"+mm;
    } 
    today = dd+':'+mm+':'+yyyy;
    console.log(today);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var fixDate = function (date){
   return date<10?"0"+date: date;
}

var dateStr = new Date();

console.log(fixDate(dateStr.getDate())+"-"+fixDate(dateStr.getMonth()+1)+"-" + dateStr.getFullYear());
```