# Have CSS render out HTML?

Tags: css, html

I have been trying to figure out a way to have my post date in my blog show up in this styled hr tag

http://cssdesk.com/juATQ

Right now there can be a symbol or static text in the line

```
content: " symbol here ";
```

How could I have my code render inside of this box so it displays my blogs post date?

I need to insert this expression.

```
 Post date: {entry_date format="%Y %m %d"}
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: Are you against the use of JS?

Comment: No just looking for any type of solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Using `:after` pseudo class**

You can use a special attr like this : [see this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after)

```
hr.style-eight:after {
    content: attr(data-date) ;
}
```

And in HTML

```
<hr class="style-eight" data-date="24-10-2013">
```

Thanks to this system, you are able to manipulate the content like you want... With some JS maybe, or with PHP using `echo date("Y m d")` (don't forget to set the timezone, something like `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');`) function.

And with jQuery : [see here for date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var today = new Date();
   var dd = today.getDate();
   var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

   var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
   if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd;}
   if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm;}
   today = yyyy+' '+mm+' '+dd;//like you want ^^ (%Y %m %d)

    $('hr.style-eight').attr('data-date', today);
});
```

**Using PURE HTML and no pseudo class `:after`**

Another way without the use of `:after` pseudo class : [Online example](http://cssdesk.com/r8EN5)

```
hr.style-eight+span { 
  display: inline-block; 
  position: relative; 
  top: -0.7em; 
  font-size: 1.5em; 
  padding: 0 0.25em; 
  background: white;
}
```

And in the HTML

```
<hr class="style-eight" />
<span>2013 10 24</span>
```