# How can I customize a Highchart filename?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a script using Highchart graphic:

http://jsfiddle.net/9C4jA/1/

And I'm tyring to customize with datetime.

Actually is saving using with filename

```
  Report.jpg
  Report.pdf
  Report.png
```

But i want to add the date

```
 Reporte_2014-14-05.jpg
 Reporte_2014-14-05.pdf
 Reporte_2014-14-05.png
```

Please somebody can help me?

Comment: Do you have some readable code instead of the massive wall o' code you have in your fiddle?

Comment: Your fiddle is the contents `exporting.js`.  Is this what you meant to do?

Comment: yes mark is all the content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is pretty simple. If you want the date you can create it like (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript)):

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} today = mm+'-'+dd+'-'+yyyy;
```

Then you need to create some sort of template file name:

```
var fileName = 'theFile_' + today;
```

Then when you export it you have a custom name:

```
exporting: {
    filename: fileName
}
```

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/844tn/).

Comment: beat me to the answer, but here's a fiddle where I was testing it out:  http://jsfiddle.net/z72yv/, I used the excellent `moment.js` to generate the date string.

Comment: Seems that i need to add something after "Report" like date

Comment: @CarlitosMorales, this is what I put into my chart declaration. Are you wanting to modify the export source js file?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-legend/   ........I'm  trying to personalize this

Comment: @CarlitosMorales, yes, this code will do that. See example in edited answer.