# How do I capture when an ID is pressed, and what time it is pressed?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I just can't seem to wrap my head around the proposal.

How can I have an array that displays which button was pressed and at what time.

The simpler the better as I'm still learning Javascript, thanks guys.

This is what I've come up with so far

```
var getTime = (document.getElementById("bass") + Date.now());
```

Comment: Why this is tagged with `android` then? because mobile devices and tablets have `tap`|`[click]`!

Comment: Because my tap is ontouchstart, I'm developing an app for android through phonegap, I maybe should of said that.

Comment: document.getElementById("bass") 
That's literally all I can think of, and that's just 1 of 4 ID's

Answer (score 0):

You should check the way you get the Date, check this:

[How do I get the current date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript)

Regards