# How can I get the current datetime in the format "2014-04-01:08:00:00" in Node?

Tags: node.js, date

I need the current system datetime in the format "yyyy-mm-dd:hh:mm:ss".

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19079030/2663388 helped a lot.

`new Date().toJSON()` is showing "2014-07-14T13:41:23.521Z"

Can someone help me to extract "yyyy-mm-dd:hh:mm:ss" from "2014-07-14T13:41:23.521Z"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems that there is no good way to do it with original code unless using Regex. There are some modules such as [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) though.

If you are using npm:

```
npm install moment --save
```

Then in your code:

```
var moment = require('moment');
moment().format('yyyy-mm-dd:hh:mm:ss');
```

That may be much easier to understand.

Comment: When I run this on a Node.js server it gives me wrong date/time in a wrong format: `2020-00-Mo-12:00:00` while running Date.toLocaleString() has the correct date/time information. Do you have an idea what might be causing this?

Comment: `mm` is for minutes, not months. Also `hh` is 12-hour time. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

`YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`

Comment: Given this was correct in 2014. moment is deprecated. moment/luxon is the latest version (with core-js to polyfill for older node and browsers)

Comment: As of 2023, the above format specifier gives something completely unexpected, for example the `dd`-part will print the name of the day of the week like `Mo`, `Tu` etc. https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/01-format/

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
new Date().toString().replace(/T/, ':').replace(/\.\w*/, '');
```

Returns for me:

```
2014-07-14:13:41:23
```

But the more safe way is using `Date` class methods which works in javascript (browser) and node.js:

```
var date = new Date();

function getDateStringCustom(oDate) {
    var sDate;
    if (oDate instanceof Date) {
        sDate = oDate.getYear() + 1900
            + ':'
            + ((oDate.getMonth() + 1 < 10) ? '0' + (oDate.getMonth() + 1) : oDate.getMonth() + 1)
            + ':' + oDate.getDate()
            + ':' + oDate.getHours()
            + ':' + ((oDate.getMinutes() < 10) ? '0' + (oDate.getMinutes()) : oDate.getMinutes())
            + ':' + ((oDate.getSeconds() < 10) ? '0' + (oDate.getSeconds()) : oDate.getSeconds());
    } else {
        throw new Error("oDate is not an instance of Date");
    }
    return sDate;
}

alert(getDateStringCustom(date));
```

Returns in node.js:
    `/usr/local/bin/node date.js 2014:07:14:16:13:10`

And in Firebug:
`2014:07:14:16:14:31`

Comment: Thanks @bernhard. I am using node.js and somehow following line -- var d = new Date().toString().replace(/T/, ':').replace(/\.\w*/, '');
    console.log(d); is showing Mon Jul 14 2014 19:30:48 GM:+0530 (IST)

Comment: But exploring this further I see 
console.log(new Date().toJSON().slice(0,19).replace('T',':')); is showing

Comment: I posted a cleaner version below.

Comment: @AlexP11223 great

Answer (score 4):

Install **moment** using

```
npm install moment --save
```

And in your code import the moment like this.

```
var moment = require('moment')
var created = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')
```

Comment: please update to moment/luxon as moment was deprecated

Comment: @TamusJRoyce please refer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment

Comment: correct. deprecated. please don't use moment. changes es2019 and core-js polyfill make moment deprecated. Please upgrade to moment/luxon. This was available in 2019

Answer (score 3):

Though other answers are helpful I found the following code is working for me.

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.toJSON().slice(0,19).replace('T',':'));
```

The output on console is: `2014-07-15:06:10:16`.
I am using Node.js Express on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Cleaner version of @Bernhard code using `padStart` and without deprecated `getYear`

```js
function getCurrentDateTimeString() {
    const date = new Date();
    return date.getFullYear() + '-' +
        (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0') + '-' +
        date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' +
        date.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' +
        date.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' +
        date.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');
}

console.log(getCurrentDateTimeString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `toLocaleString()` method in node.js

```js
let date = new Date('2014-07-14T13:41:23.521Z');
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US')); 

//Converting current date time without timezone
date = new Date()
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicity call each part of the Date:

```
function formatDate(date) {
    return [date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, date.getDate()].join('-') + ':' +
        [date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds()].join(':');
}

function formatDatePart(part) {
    return part < 10 ? ("0" + part) : part;
}
```

You can see an example on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h9Xjc/).

Answer (score 0):

Correct way is this

```
var moment = require('moment');
moment().format('Y-M-D H:m:s');
```

Comment: please update to moment/luxon as moment was deprecated