# how to get date and time together in javaScript

Tags: javascript, .net

Is there a way to get date and time in JS?
I searched in google and saw ways to get the date appart and time appart but not together.
I have a field that calls "Date Time" and i need to show data -12 hours so i need to figure out how to save datetime.
Can someone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get current date in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript)

Comment: You should check the Date object [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate) first. You have plenty examples there.

Comment: A good example on Mozilla's Developer Network: [Global objects / Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 0):

Use *javaScript* [***Date***](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) object to work with date and time.

```
alert(new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `new Date();`

```
var x = new Date();
```

You can also fetch each value using `.getDay()` , `.getMonth()`, `.getYear()`, `.getHours()`, `.getMinutes()`, `.getSeconds()`

Like

`x.getHours(); // Will give you hours.`

Answer (score 0):

use date object of javascript then adjust your date and time combinations
for example, create a function getdateTime which will return dateTime combinations

```
  function getdateTime() {
  var date = new Date();
    var dataVal=date.getDate() +"/"+ (date.getMonth() + 1)+"/" + date.getFullYear() + ":" + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes();

 return dataVal;
}

 var datetime=getdateTime();
 console.log("datetime:" +datetime);

 output for example : datetime:18/2/2015:14:26
```

ie current date and time

since months starts from 0 to 11 you have to add 1 to get current month.

you can use other date functions depending upon your requirements.