# How to get the currentDate in Javascript for IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, date

I already did some reasearch and found out that you need to format a date String because the IE can't handle some formats. But the problem is that I don't even get a current date string to format.

`Date.now()` or `Date.time()`

I also tried this if-statement:

```
if (!Date.now) {
    Date.now = function() { return new Date().getTime(); }
}
```

But I always retrieve "nan", even in IE11.

In Chrome and Firefox it works perfectly. So how do I get the currentTime in IE?

Comment: var date = new Date();

Comment: uhm... in javascript you just do new Date()? and then you have a date object with the current time. No difference between any browsers. I think you are overcomplicating things with your checks. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff743760%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Comment: [Get Current Date In JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle like this -

```
Date.prototype.now = function() { return typeof(Date.now) == 'function' ? Date.now() : new Date().getTime(); };
```

and use as,

```
var dateNow = new Date().now();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an easy work-around that should do for your problem:
Put this line at the top of your file

`Date.now = Date.now || function() { return +new Date; };`

If you need any more date formating features I can only encourage you to take a look at http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
datetField.sendKeys((d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear());
```