# Java script code to show current date only in an input box of a HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

Java script code to show only current date(not time) in an input field of a HTML page.

Comment: You have a history of off-topic or heavily downvoted questions and are at risk of losing your question-asking privileges. [You should read this before you post your next one](http://s.tk/onhold).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is in part, answered here:

[How do I get the current date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript)

From here you simply have to set the current value of a given input field, let's say it's ID is 'date'.

```
document.getElementById('date').value = dateVariable;
```