# JavaScript date displaying the wrong day and time

Tags: javascript, date

I have this application where I want to use you date, but the problem is that the date is not working as I expect.
I create a date object like this:

```
// Get today's date
today: function () {

    // Create a new date
    var date = new Date();

    // Set to midnight
    date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    // Return our date
    return date;
},
```

and If I output that date in my view I get yesterdays date at 23:00 hours....
Which looks like this:

> 2015-07-08T23:00:00.000Z

Does anyone know how I can get the date to be formatted properly?

**Update**

Just to elaborate a bit, I want to use the date to compare against records in the database. These records have the date applied to them, because the JavaScript is showing the local date time, it is not comparing correctly. Also there is a case where I am saving that date and I don't want it to save the local date.

Comment: What are you expecting to get?

Comment: Have a look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript

Comment: It displays `Thu Jul 09 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)` for me.

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me:https://jsfiddle.net/u5j5ofxu/

Comment: the date you are creating is relevant to your timezone, the date you are printing out is relevant to GMT (which you are 1hr ahead of)

Comment: Yeah, what I ended up doing was using date.ToDateString() and then parsing the date string into a timeStamp and using that instead. It seems to have worked for comparison, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up creating this function:

```
// Converts a date to a timeStamp
this.convertToTimeStamp = function (dateTime) {

    // Get just the date
    var date = dateTime.toDateString();

    // Get the timestamp
    var timeStamp = Date.parse(date);

    // Return our timeStamp
    return timeStamp;
};
```

If my understanding is correct, that should create the same date no matter what timezone / locale you are in.

Answer (score 0):

based on your culture setting you can use the

date.toLocaleDateString()

this will give localized string format back

Answer (score 0):

```
date.toUTCString();
date.toLocaleString();
date.toLocaleDateString();
date.toDateString();
date.toISOString();
```

Find your answer here :) And the best option is to use momentjs http://momentjs.com/