# Changing XML to POJO using data weave transformer in mule

Tags: mule, transformer-model, anypoint-studio

I am trying to convert a XML file to a POJO using data weave in mule, but it throws this exception -:

Message               : Exception while executing: 
        time: payload.deliveryMessageDate.time
                      ^
Type mismatch
     found :name, :binary
  required :name, :object
Type                  : com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2

---

Exception stack is:
1. Type mismatch
     found :name, :binary
  required :name, :object (com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.dynamic.DynamicDispatchException)
  com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.dynamic.DynamicDispatchNode:65 (null)
2. Exception while executing: 
        time: payload.deliveryMessageDate.time
                      ^
Type mismatch
     found :name, :binary
  required :name, :object (com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException)
  com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor:124 (null)

---

Root Exception stack trace:
com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.dynamic.DynamicDispatchException: Type mismatch
     found :name, :binary
  required :name, :object
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.dynamic.DynamicDispatchNode.dispatchNode(DynamicDispatchNode.scala:65)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.dynamic.DynamicDispatchNode.valueType(DynamicDi...

I haven't used any annotation on my POJO and the xml has some attributes inside the tags.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to format your date. try to follow the below link if you still have problem please share your logic screen that will give clear idea.

[Converting to a date format in Mule using DataWeave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33075127/converting-to-a-date-format-in-mule-using-dataweave)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose Your Json is 
{
  "date": "2016-13-09"
}

Data weave for converting date is :-

date : payload.date  as :date {format: "yyyy-dd-MM"} as :string{format: "yyyyMMdd"}

Firstly its match date and then convert to your specific formats.