# how to convert yyyymmdd into mm-dd-yyyy in dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have two string 1 represent date and 2nd time. have to convert same into date format in Mule-dataweave

input :-
s1= 20161228(yyyymmdd), 
s2= 1608(hhmm)

output :-
12-28-2016 16:08:00(mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss) in date format.

Any Help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33075127/converting-to-a-date-format-in-mule-using-dataweave may help you

Comment: I have done this but will it be able to convert into date??

    
%dw 1.0    


%output application/java    


%input payload application/json   



%var Cdate = payload.mdate[4..5] ++ "-" ++ payload.mdate[6..7] ++ "-" ++ payload.mdate[0..3]


%var Ctime = payload.mtime[0..1] ++ ":" ++ payload.mtime[2..3] ++ ":00"


---

<b>
Cdate ++ " " ++ Ctime </b>

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
%var s1= 20161228 // (yyyymmdd), 
%var s2= 1608 //(hhmm)
---
output :  (s1 ++ s2) as :localdatetime {format:"yyyyMMddHHmm"} as :string {format:"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ "data":payload.date as {format:"MM/DD/YY"}as :string{format:"dd/mm/yy"} }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert as given below.

```
DATUM: input as :localdatetime {format: "yyyymmdd"} as :string {format: "yyyyMMdd"},
DATUM: now as :string {format: "mm-dd-yyyy"}
```

For more about date formats see the below link.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-types#dates