# Date type conversion in dataweave

Tags: mule, transformation, dataweave, mulesoft

I am tryng to build a Date fromat conversion in Mule using dataweave.
The problem is: I am receiving the Date information as: 'Thy Feb 17 00:00:00 BRT 2022'. I need to transform this to the format YYYYMMDD.
I try to create my specific function but the problem start when Mule tries to parse the received date as a date.

```
  'Thu Feb 17 00:00:00 BRT 2022' could not be parsed at index 0.
```

Can you guys help me with that transformation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting to a date format in Mule using DataWeave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33075127/converting-to-a-date-format-in-mule-using-dataweave)

Comment: I think that my problem is this 'BRT' as time zone in the middle of the string... It looks like Datetime don´t accept it.

Comment: No built the format LocalDateTime {format: "EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss zzz yyyy"} for 'Thy Feb 17 00:00:00 BRT 2022' the result was:
'Cannot coerce LocalDataTime (|2022-02-17T00:00:00| as  LocalDateTime {format: "EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss zzz yyyy"}) to String, caused by: Unable to extract ZoneId from temporal 2022-02-17T00:00:00'

Comment: Thy for Thursday?? Ideally it should be Thu @ChelloFera

Answer (score 0):

I got it!
In my case, it was an env configuration in the Java VM options.
Go to the menu '*Run->Run Configurations*' and select the tab '*Arguments*'.
In the field 'VM arguments' add the Java Options: "**-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Duser.varian=EN**"

This solves the problem for me!

Comment: The names for days and months are dependent on the locale of the JVM. If you are running in an OS configured with a different locale it makes sense the names don't match.