# Current date in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

How would I get the current date to display in jquery as "Saturday, October 31, 2015"? I can only find how to get the date to display as "dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: There is no built in Date formatting in jQuery. http://momentjs.com/

Comment: You can use moment.js: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: you can also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript

Comment: I am not really sure how to implement moments.js,

Comment: Would it be impossible for me to learn to do this in PHP if its so easy?

Comment: `$today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");  // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001 `

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php you can check this link too

Comment: [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

```
var date = new Date();

var str = ["Sunday", "mon", "tues", "wed", "thurs", "fri", "sat", "sun"][date.getDay()];
str += ", " + ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "june", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "November", "dec"][date.getMonth()];
str += " "  + date.getDate();
str += ", " + date.getFullYear();

console.log(str);
```

> `Sunday, November 1, 2015`

Comment: Amazing!! beautiful ty Alex

Answer (score 2):

To get **31/10/2015** use this :

```
// "31/10/2015" and august : 31/08/2015 :
var a=new Date();
alert([("0" + a.getDate()).slice(-2), ("0" + (a.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2), a.getFullYear()].join("/"));

// "31/10/2015" and august : 31/8/2015 :
[a.getDate(), (a.getMonth() + 1), a.getFullYear()].join("/");
```

**Example :**

```js
function getDate() {
  var a=new Date();
  return [("0" + a.getDate()).slice(-2), ("0" + (a.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2), a.getFullYear()].join("/");
}


document.write(getDate());
```

Comment: She ask for `Thursday, October 31, 2015` not `31/09/2015` and the current date is `31/10/2015` =)

Answer (score 1):

To get Sat Oct 31 2015 use this:

```
var TodaysDate = new Date().toDateString();
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j7f1v3kd/)