# How to change Dateformat in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have get Date in jQuery but this `2016-01-06T00:00:00+05:30` Format, But I want to only `06-01-2016` format.

Comment: Please write what have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current date in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with just a litle bit of string parsing

```
var date   = "2016-01-06T00:00:00+05:30";

var split  = date.split('T').shift();   // 2016-01-06

var parts  = split.split('-');          // [2016, 01, 06]

var parsed = parts.reverse().join('-'); // 06-01-2016
```

Assuming the date is a string, as posted, not a date object, and not coming from a datepicker that supports formatting with `$.format`

Answer (score 1):

try this example

```
document.write($.format.date("2009-12-18 10:54:50.546", "Test: dd/MM/yyyy"));

 //output Test: 18/12/2009
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in JavaScript..

```
var fullDate = new Date();

//convert month to 2 digits
var twoDigitMonth = ((fullDate.getMonth().length+1) === 1)? (fullDate.getMonth()+1) : '0' + (fullDate.getMonth()+1);
var currentDate = fullDate.getDate() + "-" + twoDigitMonth + "-" + fullDate.getFullYear();
```

and you can [refer this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-todays-date-ddmmyyyy/) for further..

Answer (score 0):

**use moment.js**
and this fuction

```
function ParseDate(day) {
  var value = new Date(
    parseInt(day.replace(/(^.*\()|([+-].*$)/g, ''))
  );

  var dat;
  if (value.getDate() < 10) {
    var dat =
      value.getFullYear() + "/" + (parseFloat(value.getMonth()) + 1) + "/" + "0" + value.getDate();
  } else {
    var dat = value.getFullYear() + "/" + (parseFloat(value.getMonth()) + 1) + "/" + value.getDate();
  }
  return dat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var date = new Date("2016-01-06T00:00:00+05:30");
day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2)
m = date.getMonth()+1;
month = ("0" + m).slice(-2)
yr = date.getFullYear();
var formatted = day+"-"+month+"-"+yr;
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/9ty4u2tf/)