# How to pass JavaScript function to the INPUT HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html

This is all I want.

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="date" value="currentdate()">
.....</form>
```

Here I want to set default value as a current date.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript may help you

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can do that.

But this would work:

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
  dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
  mm='0'+mm
} 

today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;

document.getElementById('date').value=today ;
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="date" id="date">
</form>
```

I got this solution from [Samuel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4929629/4802649) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript).

Comment: Didn't work. Is there any other way to do that? I really want this.

Comment: Then don't forget to pick up the accepted answer to help the future user find a solution as you did.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a default value to a input, in the DOM, using the document.ready function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("myInput").defaultValue = myCustomFunction();});
```

Comment: perhaps also include how to set the value to the current date?

Answer (score 1):

While the question is really unclear and I would recommend an edit be done BY YOU, I will attempt it...

```
<form action="page.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="date" value="Enter the date here!" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
.....
```

I dunno if this is what you want but if you want to pass it to a handler you'd need to Google form actions and change the first line's "action" attribute then delete the 'method="post"' part unless you want it.

(Note: The reason I feel like this is what you want is because you made the input a text area... Why would you do that if you want it to display the current date?)

Comment: Eventhough it is text area, I want to pass default value as a result of some js function.  Sorry, I don't know much about coding.