# Hide/Disable Text in HTML with Javascript Date Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, show-hide

I'm trying to hide a header  on my site for most of the year and have it reappear for four weeks at a time based off of a specific date.

I have had a few suggestions on how to do this, but am coming up empty as I am a real beginner on web programming.

I'd also like to test the code in something like jsfiddle.net

Your help is greatly appreciated.

For Example:

**Holiday Specials**
[if today is April 1st to April 29th show text]
[if today is April 30 hide text]

Comment: What have you tried so far, what problems are you having? Please show us your code and where your problem is at and then we can help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You'll find answers to programming problems you are having and the best questions have example code that you're having a problem with.  Give it your best shot and come back if it isn't working and ask for help.  Also you may want to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have tried JS date objects and jquery. Being a noob I know js probably should be installed to test but I thought jsfiddle took care of that. I can post snippets of the code if you want.

Comment: Note that the host system can be set to any time and time zone, so you absolutely should not trust the client to present messages at a particular time if you care at all about security and fraud prevention. This should be done on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javascript date formatting can be unpleasant. You typically have to use multiple methods to get a date into a usable format.

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4929629/4734481) answer from another question, I've created the following jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/pkbnok8o/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  dateMethod();
});

function dateMethod() {
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear(); //You won't need this for this question, but I kept it in for knowledge.

  if (dd < 10) { //Won't need this logic either.
    dd = '0' + dd
  }

  if (mm < 10) { //Also will not need this logic
    mm = '0' + mm
  }
  
  if (mm == 4 && dd >= 1 && dd <= 29){ //This will show the text any year between 4/1 and 4/29 (including both of those days)
   $("#txt").show(); //This uses jQuery
  } else{ //Otherwise, the text will be hidden
   $("#txt").hide(); //This is also jQuery
  }

  today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy; //Probably don't need/want this
  $("#currentDate").text(today); //or this.
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Today is:
<label id="currentDate"></label>
<br />
<label id="txt">Test Text</label>
```

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) has some pretty good information on the different `get` methods for javascript time & dates. Scroll down on that link to the Date Object Methods.

Comment: I updated https://jsfiddle.net/pkbnok8o/1/ to give a real life example of what I am looking for and hid the first part of your text. Would this turn off on April 30th and turn back on next year from April 1st to April 29th? thank you for the help

Comment: Why create a Date object then compare the parts individually? Why not `if (new Date() > new Date(2016,3,1)){/* after 1 April*/}`.

Comment: @chrish The way it is setup currently it would only hide on 4/30 of any year. If you want to only show it between 4/1 and 4/29 then you would say

`if (mm == 4 && dd >= 1 && DD <= 29){ $("#txt").show(); } else { $("#txt").hide(); }`

That will hide it all year long until the month is 4 (april) and the day is between the 1st and the 29th, and it would display on the 1st and the 29th as well.

Comment: @RobG the purpose of creating the entire date object was only to help chrish better understand javascript dates.

Comment: There is an extra curly bracket in the else statement `$("#txt").hide(); }`, would need to remove that, and then you can probably also get rid of the two if statements above that do `dd = '0' + dd;` and `mm = '0' + mm;` since you only care about the integer value. Looks good though.

If you are going to want it to cutout at a specific time as well (12 o'clock) then you will need to checkout the w3schools link at the end of my answer and do some research on JS time formats. & as others have mentioned you would want to be careful when using JS date & times since timezones can be different

Comment: @mighty_mite I made updates and changes here https://jsfiddle.net/pkbnok8o/5/ BUT for some reason Father's Day, Ind Day, and Labor Day appear when they should be hidden. Any suggestions? Thank you for all the help.

Comment: You'll want to change `DD` to `dd`. Javascript is case sensitive for variables. Looks like you've got the idea though.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide/show information using jQuery effects

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
});
$("#show").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>

<button id="hide">Hide</button> 
<button id="show">Show</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, the user wants to show some content based on the date.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id='april_holiday_specials'>
  <h2>April Specials<h2>
</div>
<div id='other_specials'>
  <h2>Other Specials<h2>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  var today = new Date();

if (today.getMonth() == 3 && today.getDate() > 0 && today.getDate() < 30) {

  $("#april_holiday_specials").show();
  $("#other_specials").hide();

} else {

  $("#april_holiday_specials").hide();
  $("#other_specials").show();
}
});
```

Refer w3c date for more info on js date : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lcb4tyxm/4/

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I was trying to explain. I want to have the "Holiday Specials" to be displayed. It appears from April 1 to April 29 and then hides from the site on April 30th onward, until the following year it reappears from April 1-April29th.

Comment: @chrish Edited my answer as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to hide the element by default and use 
and use a script to check the date every time the page is loaded up.

When the current date is within the given month then show the element.

```
// @param selector <String>
function showElement(selector) {
  document.querySelector(selector).style.display = "block"
}

/** 
  @param startDate <Integer> 
  @param startMonth <Integer>
**/
function isInFourWeekPeriod(startDate, startMonth) {
  var d = new Date()
  var currentDate = d.getDate()
  var currentMonth = d.getMonth() + 1

  if (currentMonth !== startMonth || currentMonth !== startMonth + 1)
    return false

  if ((currentDate < startDate) && (currentMonth === startMonth))
    return false

  if ((currentDate > startDate) && (currentMonth === startMonth + 1))
    return false

  return true
}

if (isInFourWeekPeriod())
  showElement("#my-banner-text")

// HTML file
<style>
  #my-banner-text {
    display: none;
  }  
</style>
<header>
  <div id="my-banner-text">
    my text
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the client system clock can be set to any time and time zone, so if you care about fraud or security, you must not depend on the client system for anything important.

Otherwise, you can compare Date objects directly, so to see if a date is before, on or after a specific date, use date objects, e.g.

```js
// Create Dates for specific local dates
var startDate = new Date(2016,3,1);
var endDate   = new Date(2016,3,30);

// Create a Date for the current local time
var now       = new Date();

// Do some comparisons
if (now > startDate) {
  show(now + ' is after ' + startDate);
}
if (now < endDate) {
  show(now + ' is before ' + endDate);
}
show('Today is ' + (now.setHours(0,0,0,0) == endDate? '' : 'not ') + 'the last day');
       

  
function show(s) {
  document.write('<br>' + s);
}
```

So you can send the parameters for the start and end dates, then use the client system to generate a date for the current time (noting the above caveat that this is **not reliable**). Then just compare the dates using less than, greater than and equals operators.