# Removing time from a javascript variable that holds data and time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a query that reads a date like this

```
var getstatusdate = $('#statusdate').val();

getstatusdate = "6/14/2016 12:00:00 AM"
```

Need to compare with another variable that stores date in the format below

```
var today = "06/14/2016"
```

How do I remove the time from getstatusdate and make it look like "06/14/2016"

I tried this but no luck.

```
var cleaneddate = getstatusdate.toDateString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: Possibly this will answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks. Am not trying to get a new date. I just need to format an existing date.

Comment: @user2320476 If you look at the accepted answer for that question drew_w posted, it shows you how to format the date

Comment: Also, if you are not comparing equality, but rather < or > , you can simply use new Date(getstatusdate).getTime() < new Date(today).getTime()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are taking `new Date()` then like this

```
var dt = new Date();
var myDate = dt.getDate() + "/" +parseInt(dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
alert(dt); //Tue Jun 14 2016 21:12:07...
alert(myDate); //14/6/2016
```

else based on your given date, you can use `split()` as follow

```
getstatusdate = "6/14/2016 12:00:00 AM"
alert(getstatusdate.split(" ")[0]); //6/14/2016
```

Comment: A half-hearted attempt to answer the question. OP specifically stated MM/dd/yyyy format

Comment: This looks a lot better. You are splitting with (" ")[0]. Could you explain this?

Comment: @user2320476 http://stackoverflow.com/a/4929629/4987197 is what you are looking for.

Comment: @user2320476 I used separator as space and as it returns array so accessed first element of it,  you can have more details about `split()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: @Hearty - will it be possible to return two digits for the month. More like this "06/14/2016"

Comment: Please ignore the last question. I was able to figure it out.

Comment: Okay no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

In alternative, if you don't want to manage dates but manipulate strings, you can use a regex like this one;

```
var getstatusdate = $('#statusdate').val();
var myRegexp = ^(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d)(.*);
var match = myRegexp.exec(getstatusdate);

var cleaneddate = match[1];
```

match group 1 matches 
starting string (^)
with:
2 digit
\
2 digit
\
4 digit

rest it's optional and ignored (=> in match[2])