# How do I create time string based on Date.now

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to create a string indicating current date, in such a format:
Javascript or Typescript:

```
2017-01-09T15:00:00Z
```

I would like to generate it based on current time. What would be the easiest approach. The other way is simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: and of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript too ?

Answer (score 0):

Moment.js is good for many different styles of date formatting.
http://momentjs.com/

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a') // August 30th 2016, 11:44:55 am
```