# jquery shows wrong date

Tags: jquery, html

I want to show the current date in my invoice. To do this, im using the following method:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Datum:
<p id="date"></p>

<script>
    var today = new Date();
    var day = today.getDay();
    var month = today.getMonth();
    var year = today.getYear();
    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = day + "." + month + "." + year;

</script>
```

Comment: is this maybe something that your server is updating?

Comment: Please, and some more information about your problem, such as the console error, bad behaviors etc.

Comment: That isn't jQuery. Its javascript. And `.getDay()` will return a number between 0 and 6. You want `.getDate()`

Comment: Be sure, the `getDay` method returns day of week. So, for now it returns 1(Monday). And the `getMonth` returns month from 0 to 11.

Comment: I dont know if it matter but jquery is at ver 3.1 now  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: It doesn't throw any error, but the date is not correct. It shows: 1.9.116, whereas it should be 31.10.2016

Comment: Furthermore, you probably want today.getFullYear() not getYear(). The former returns the full year since 0 AD and the latter is deprecated.

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript

Comment: Since January starts with 0 you need to make update in your month section as:  
     today.getMonth() + 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [check the manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay):

**getDay** - method returns the day of the week for the specified date according to local time, where 0 represents Sunday
**getMonth** - An integer number, between 0 and 11, representing the month in the given date according to local time. 0 corresponds to January, 1 to February, and so on.
**getYear** - A number representing the year of the given date, according to local time, minus 1900

What you are actually looking for is:

```html
<p id="date"></p>
<script>
    var today = new Date();
    var day = today.getDate();
    var month = today.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = today.getFullYear();
    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = day + "." + month + "." + year;

</script>

</html>
```

And it has nothing to do wth jQuery :) it's pure javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your solution.