# error in adding Date to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I am trying to insert system date to DB but there is an error "non-invocable member 'tostring' cannot be used like a method". Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
public partial class code : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
[WebMethod]
public static bool register(string rusrid, string rname, string raddress,       
string rcity,string rdistrict,string rstate,int rpin,string rlanph,string  
rmob,string rgen, string remail,string rpass)
{

 bool msg = false;
 string constr = 
 ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
 {
 con.Open();
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("user_reg", con);
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


 cmd.Parameters.Add("@Jdate", SqlDbType.Date).Value =    
 DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cstatus", '1');


 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 msg = true;
 }
 return msg;
}

}
```

In my Data base the date column's data type is set as date

Comment: Instead of including an image of your code, please include it as text. This will help future readers who have a similar problem find your question through search.

Comment: have you tried to instanciate your date into a variable before adding it as a parameter

Comment: no i haven't tried that

Comment: You should do something like this [How do I get the current date in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript).

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL Hm, no.  Using the server's current date is probably the way to go.

Comment: @James the code in that answer gives you the current date in JavaScript