# how to get date in YYYY-MM-DD format in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, date, angular2-services

I want to get date in the following format: YYYY-MM-DD.

I wrote a date service in Angular2 based on this question: 
[How do I get the current date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript).

I wanted to check if it is a correct implementation or if there exists a better way to achieve the goal.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DateService {
private currentDate = new Date();

    getCurrentDateInApiFormat(): string{
        let day:any = this.currentDate.getDate();
        let month:any = this.currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
        let year:any = this.currentDate.getFullYear();
        let dateInApiFormat: string;

        if(day<10){
           day = '0' + day.toString();
        }
        if(month<10){
            month = '0' + month.toString();
        }
        dateInApiFormat = day + '-' + month + '-' + year.toString();
        return dateInApiFormat;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You could simply use the **[`Date Pipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)**

```
 <p>The time is {{currentDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</p>
```

and in TS

```
export class App {

 currentDate: number = Date.now();

}
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/ngDJ7CJc9V5LX4sfqyYt?p=preview)**

Answer (score 3):

```
  // To use date service 

   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

   @Injectable()

   export class DateService {

      public currentDate = new Date();

       getCurrentDateInApiFormat() {
          const date = currentDate;
          const month = ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
          const day = ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2);

          return [date.getFullYear(), month, day].join('-');
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The different date format can be achievable through moment.js library.
You can just import/add it. and use the following syntax to convert your timestamp to date string.

moment.tz(this.value, 'GMT').format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');

Here tz is timezone.