# Pull out time of day in Javascript / Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am trying to figure out how to pull out the time of day in Javascript. I am then going to band these depending on the time e.g. 8-11am = Breakfast.

I know how to do that part but can't figure out how to pull out the time of day itself.

Comment: You mean the current time?

Comment: You mean `var now = new Date(); console.log(now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds())` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the current date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript)