# How to display just date and no time with UTC datestring in js?

Tags: javascript

Trying to display just the date by doing this:

```
let myDate="2015-03-08T04:49:49.431Z";
console.log(new Date(myDate).toUTCString('dd-mm-yyyy'));
```

Still returns the time , how can I just return the date?

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the current date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myDate="2015-03-08T04:49:49.431Z";
new Date(myDate).toLocaleDateString(); // "3/8/2015"
new Date(myDate).toDateString(); // "Sun Mar 08 2015"
```

You can check all other methods here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: However this does not give you the **dd-mm-yyyy** format.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
let myDate = "2015-03-08T04:49:49.431Z";
let date = new Date(myDate);
let dateString = ("0" + date.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + (date.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "-" + date.getUTCFullYear();
console.log(dateString);
```

`.toUTCString()` does not accept any arguments.