# return todays date in JS

Tags: javascript

Using node.js on a lambda in aws why does

```
const todaysDate = Date.now();
```

return todays date as '1513319707926'

I know the format is wrong but iv tried const `todaysDate = Date.now().format('MM/DD/YYYY');` and that doesnt fire

all I want is todays date to equal for example 15/12/2017

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the current date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```js
const todaysDate =new Date();
console.log((todaysDate.getMonth()+1)+'/'+todaysDate.getDate()+'/'+todaysDate.getFullYear());
```

Answer (score 0):

here what you want

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){
    dd='0'+dd;
} 
if(mm<10){
    mm='0'+mm;
} 
var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = today;`
```