# Save the current Date and Time in firebaseDatabase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am sending Data from a js.function to Firebase Database. The Data are consisting of two strings and 1 Data/time Variable the source code of the js function is the following:

```
$('#send_button').click(function(){
  rootRef.push({
    title:$('#title').val(),
    description:$('#description').val(),
    time: `${new Date().getTime()}.txt`;

    });

})
```

The function works perfect, my firebase database receives the content but it loos like this?

[image]

The time variable is storing just random numbers instead of the current date, is there any way to fix this?

Thanks in Regards

Answer (score 1):

> `new Date().getTime()` method returns how many milliseconds have
>   passed since `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT`.

You can use `toDateString()` to convert date object in string

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript ISO Dates</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = new Date().toDateString();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can use `toUTCString()` to convert date object in string along with time

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <h2>JavaScript ISO Dates</h2>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = new Date().toUTCString();
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't random number, you used the 'getTime()' function which return the numeral time from the beginning of the world...obviously joking.

Read this: [Date.prototype.getTime() - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

Also this: [How do I get the current date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript)

Hopes it help!

Comment: Ahah not from the beginning of the world =p  But  from the 01/01/1970 ^^

Answer (score 0):

The GetTime method return the numeric value of a date ( so it's normal you have a number )

try this instead :

```
time: `${new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]}.txt`;
```