# set current date as default in an input of type date

Tags: html, typescript, materialize

I have an input of type `date`, where I use materialize to pick a date. I want to have the current date as default on init.

**HTML**

```
<input formControlName="invoice_date" id="invoice_date" type="date" class="datepicker" materialize="pickadate" [materializeParams]="[{ format: 'yyyy-mm-dd', formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
          closeOnSelect: true, selectMonths: true, selectYears: true, today: '',
          max: true, onSet: onSetDatepicker }]">
```

**JavaScript**

```
  onSetDatepicker(date) {
    if (date.select) {
      $('#invoice_date').pickadate().pickadate('picker').close();
    }
  }
```

Comment: The datepicker function should have today as its default value by default through the datepicker library. You could however just set the value of the input field to be <?php echo date('y-m-d'); ?>

Answer (score 2):

```js
var date = new Date();

var day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

var today = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);

$('#dateid').val(today);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="date" id="dateid">
```

Answer (score 0):

The datepicker libray usually have the current day as its default starting point, so I'm not sure why you have it differently. However, what you could do is set the `value` of the input field to contain the date of today.

Example:

```
<input formControlName="invoice_date" id="invoice_date" type="date" class="datepicker" 
materialize="pickadate" [materializeParams]="[{ 
format: 'yyyy-mm-dd', formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
          closeOnSelect: true, selectMonths: true, selectYears: true, today: '',
          max: true, onSet: onSetDatepicker }]" 
value="<?php echo date('y-m-d'); ?>">
```

Comment: thnx for the answer ... yes , the the default starting point is the current day, but how can i have it as a default input, tried this, doesnt work...

Comment: Then I don't understand what you mean, this should show the value of today in the input as the actual value. What does this "do" in your case? Just nothing?

Comment: nothing..its blank...event when i try to put a random date as a default value it doesnt show...i dont understand

Comment: Seems like you might have something that overwrites its value. Do you have any other JavaScript that interferes with what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help your problem in setting the default value of date as current date.

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        let today = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
        var options = {
            defaultDate: new Date(today),
            setDefaultDate: true
        };
        var elems = document.querySelector('.datepicker');
        var instance = M.Datepicker.init(elems, options);
        instance.setDate(new Date(today));
});
</script>
```

[How do I get the current date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35922073/8437974)