# Calling current date in a function

Tags: javascript

I have a function call `getPassportExpiryDate`:

```
     function getPassportExpiryDate() {
         return new Date(2019, 8, 17);
      }
```

I want `(2019, 8, 17)` to be dynamic instead of static date, according to the current date.

Comment: just `new Date();`

Comment: just a `new Date()` will do the trick.

Comment: So basically you just want to return current date? If that is so, just `return new Date()` should do the trick.

Comment: As per your code, I can guess that you don't want the current date as the expiry date of the passport may be fixed, Do you want to calculate the expiry date from the current date?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the current date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `new Date()`, don't pass anything inside your Date object.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getPassportExpiryDate() {
  return new Date();
}
console.log(getPassportExpiryDate())
```