# Adding a html table to html form and save to same file

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I found [this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hypertexthero/htmlformtofile/master/index.html) online and it is very helpful. This script creates a new file and saves the form.

In addition to this form, I added HTML table to the same HTML script. How do I download the HTML table along with the other contents of this index.html file into the same text file?

See the code snippet below:

```js
// Current date - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4929629/412329
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if(dd<10) {
        dd='0'+dd
        } 

    if(mm<10) {
        mm='0'+mm
        } 

    today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;


    function saveFormAsTextFile()
        // Based on https://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/loading-editing-and-saving-a-text-file-in-html5-using-javascrip/
        {
        var textToSave =
          '---\n'+
          'title: ' + document.getElementById('title').value + '\n' + // =title
          'location: ' + document.getElementById('location').value + '\n' + // =location
          'date: ' + today + '\n' + // =date - automatically puts today's date =todo: fix bug allowing going over 60 seconds, i.e. 61 seconds
          'senses: ' + document.getElementById('senses').value + '\n' + // =senses - select menu
          'tags: ' + '\n- ' + document.getElementById('tags').value.replace(/,\s/g, "\n- ") + '\n' + 
            // =tags
            // The replace() bit above converts 'tag,tag' to '- tag\n- tag\n' with regular expressions
            // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp
          '---\n' + '\n' + 
          document.getElementById('content').value // =content;

        var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {type:"text/plain"});
        var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
        var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("filename").value;

        var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
        downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
        downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
        downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

        downloadLink.click();
        }

    function destroyClickedElement(event)
        {
        document.body.removeChild(event.target);
        }
```

```css
 body {font-family:verdana, sans-serif; color:#666; background:#fafafa; padding:20px; text-align:center;}
    #page {text-align:left; max-width:600px; margin:0 auto;} 
    h1 {font-size:16px; font-weight:normal; text-align:center;}
    label {font-size:16px;}
    label i {font-style:normal; display:inline-block; text-align:right; width:100px;}
    label textarea {vertical-align:top;}
    button {margin-left:105px; padding:5px; margin-top:5px; font-size:16px;}
    input, textarea {width:400px; font-size:16px; font-family: courier, "courier new", monospace; margin:0 0 5px 0; padding:5px; border:1px solid #eee;}
    select {margin:0 0 5px 0;}
    @media (min-width:300px) and (max-width: 768px) {
      input, textarea {width:100%;}
      label i {display:block; width:auto; text-align:left;}
      button {display:block; margin:0;}
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 
  <title>New Post</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page">
    
    <h1>New Post</h1>
  
    <label for="title">
      <i>Title</i> <!-- =title - input example -->
      <input id="title" size="40" placeholder="Title">
    </label>
    
    <br>
    
    <label for="title">
      <i>Location</i> <!-- =location - input example -->
      <input id="location" size="40" placeholder="Location">
    </label>
    
    <input type="hidden" id="date" size="40"> <!-- =date - hidden input example (automatically populated with current date in yyyy-mm-dd format) -->
    
    <br>
    
    <label for="senses"> 
      <i>Senses</i> <!-- =senses select menu example -->
      <select name="senses" id="senses" size="1">
        <option value="Touch">Touch</option>
        <option value="Sound">Sound</option>
        <option value="Sight">Smell</option>
        <option value="Sight">Taste</option>
        <option value="Sight">Sight</option>
      </select>
    </label>
    
    <br>
    
    <label for="tags">
      <i>Tags</i>  <!-- =tags textarea example -->
      <textarea id="tags" cols="40" rows="3" placeholder="tag, tag, tag"></textarea>
    </label>
    
    <br>
    
    <label for="content">
    <i>Content</i>  <!-- =content textarea example -->
    <textarea id="content" cols="40" rows="10" placeholder="Write something."></textarea>
    </label>

    <br>
    
    <label for="filename">
      <i>Filename</i>
      <input id="filename" value="" size="40" placeholder="title.md">
    </label>
    
    <button onclick="saveFormAsTextFile()">
      Save to File
    </button>
    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi there! It's kind of hard to help without seeing any of your code. Can you post the relevant code in your question? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @AndroidNoobie I added the relevant code, thank u for the suggestion.

Comment: @Tim where's the table?