# how to provide the date as filename using javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, filenames

i have written some code in javascript, and i want to use today's date as my file name, even i tried below code but it wont work for me.

```
filename=${`any_name_${new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10)}.zip
```

can anyone help me with it?

Comment: `filename = \`any_name_${new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10)}.zip\``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use string concatenation:

```
var filename="any_name_" + new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10) + ".zip";
console.log(filename)
```

Output:

```
any_name_2019-04-04.zip
```

Comment: As i use
 console.log=(`${(new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10).toString())}.zip`); 
and it's working fine.

Comment: You can do `console.log("any_name_" + new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10) + ".zip")`

Comment: I just want to print the date as file name, without affecting any other character.
console.log("any_name_" + new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10) + ".zip") – 
if i use this approach then the file name will get print ""any_name_2019-04-04.zip"" like this.

Comment: If you only want the date followed by `.zip`, do `console.log(new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10) + ".zip")`

Answer (score 15):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to accomplish this:

```js
let filename = `any_name_${(new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10))}.zip`
console.log(`Add here ${filename}`);
```

Comment: output looks like this: 2022-02-11

Answer (score 4):

All the answers listed above just create a new Date, then look at the first part of it. However, JS Dates include timezones. As of writing this (1/6/22 @ 9PM in Eastern/US), if I run:

```js
let filename = `any_name_${(new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10))}.zip`
console.log(`Add here ${filename}`);
```

it falsely gives me tommorows date (1/7/22). This is because Date() just looking at the first part of the date is ignoring the timezone.

A better way to do this that takes into account timezones is:

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

filename = mm + '-' + dd + '-' + yyyy + '.zip';
console.log(filename);
```

Adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4929629/10197738).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ES6 standards, we can use Template_literals
Ref : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```js
const filename = `any_name_${new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10)}.zip`;
```