# How can I compare a DateTime.toShortTimeString to a DateTime.now?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a field that displays a value (lets call it startTime) in ShortTimeString() format & would like to compare this to DateTime.Now in such a way that:

```
if (startTime.AddMinutes(5) > DateTime.Now){ //do a thing; }
```

(if startTime was 5 minutes ago or greater, do a thing)

Need a way to convert startTime from a String back to a DateTime so that I can then compare.

Comment: C# **or** JavaScript...? You should really pick one or the other for the sake of keeping the question properly scoped. Without specifying a language, it could be argued this is too broad and not useful to future readers.

Comment: Sorry, edited now to remove c# tag - will stick to jquery

Comment: Have you tried anything? There are many hundreds of questions about parsing dates, comparing dates, etc. in JavaScript on Stack Overflow...

Comment: There's no such thing as a `DateTime` in JavaScript. There's [the `Date` type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), which has documented methods and properties...

Comment: @HereticMonkey ahh. forgive me. Im currently using a mix of JS & c# to perform different functions in my code so thats where my confusion & mixing up of terminologies is coming in

Answer (score 1):

Example of subtracting 2 dates.

```
var date1 = new Date("6/8/1969 20:30:00");
var date2 = new Date("6/20/1969 19:15:00");

var diff = date2 - date1;
```

or in your case:

```
var diff = Date.now() - Date.parse(startTime);  //if startTime is invalid, watchout!
```

or

```
 var diff = Date.now() - new Date(startTime);   // I prefer this
```

useful link here:

[How do I get the current date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank You. This is along the lines of what I need, but moreso struggling with figuring out a way to convery startTime back into a Date first before the comparison

Comment: to parse from string:  `var dt = Date.parse("11/30/2011");`  I will update my answer.

Comment: Why might diff return NaN here?
`startTime = $(".sessionStartTime").text();

var diff = Date.now() - Date.parse(startTime);

alert(diff);`

Comment: the Date.Parse() probably isn't working, check it.. have you tried simple `new Date(startTime);` instead of parse?

Comment: Yup I tried it out. I'm gonna keep messing around and hopefully I can figure it out from here. You've definitely put me on the right path so thank you very much for your time