# Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'Date' and 'number'.ts(2365)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using angular 8 application and I have this function:

```
 checkExpired(echeq: EcheqSubmissionApi) {
    const today = Date.now();
    const validUntil = echeq.validUntilUtc;
    if (validUntil < today) {
      echeq.status = EcheqSubmissionStatus.EXPIRED;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

and

```
   validUntilUtc?: Date;
```

But I get this error:

```
Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'Date' and 'number'.ts(2365)
```

on this line:

```
if (validUntil < today) {
```

How to correct this?

Comment: if (validUntil < today `)` { try

Comment: ?? Dont understand what you mean

Comment: change `if (validUntil < today { ` into `if (validUntil < today ) {` add the `)`

Comment: Ah, come on. That was type. I already corrected. But that is not the issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the current date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript)

Comment: @codeFreak [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970. That is a number. Use `new Date()` to get the current date as a `Date` object.

Comment: The error seems quite clear. You're trying to compare a date and a number. So, either convert the date to a number or vice versa.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `Date.now()` returns a type of `number` thus the type inconsistency. Try converting your `validUntil` to the millisecond representation of that date and then compare to `today`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

Answer (score 0):

*Hint1:-*  try casting date something like this

```
const validUntil = new Date(echeq.validUntilUtc);
```

*Hint2:-*  or u can directly change the type of validUntilUtc to Date

```
validUntilUtc : Date;
```

now the operator shld work in below case

```
if (validUntil < today) {
....
}
```