# How to convert json date to gate in ionic 4

Tags: android, angular, date, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to convert a date.

JSON response:

```
{"success":1,
    "event_details":[
    {"id":"1","place_id":"0","title":"sdgf","description":"<p>gsdgs<\/p>\r\n","event_date":"1970-01-01 00:00:00","status":"1"}
    ]
}
```

date from json response :
**2020-02-17 03:15:00**

I want to convert it like :
**17-2-2020**

In dd/mm/YYYY format

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript

Comment: `console.log(new Date('2020-02-17 03:15:00').toLocaleDateString('hi-IN');)`

Answer (score 0):

use Moment.js to change date format-

eg:

```
convertDate(event_date: any) {
    return moment(event_date).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Install moment in your project by below command

```
npm install moment --save
```

In your page where you want to use this library import library

```
import Moment from 'moment'
```

on your code convert it

```
moment(event_date).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

If your purpose of doing this is only to show in UI

then you can use **IONIC** internal thing from here

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime

Answer (score 0):

If you're using angular then use the `DatePipe` https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Do something like this in your template file,

```
'2020-02-17 03:15:00' | date: 'dd-mm-YYYY' // -> 17-02-2020
```

or

```
class MyComponent {
   pipe = new DatePipe('en-US');
   const dateTransformed = pipe.transform('2020-02-17', 'dd-mm-YYYY');
}
```