# Moment.js retrieving a different date when using toDate() and format()

Tags: javascript, typescript, datetime, momentjs

I need to get the current date in my TypeScript application. It is now 13:35 for me.

When using `moment(Date.now()).toDate()` I get the current date, but an hour too early than what I would expect: 
*"2020-03-26T12:35:12.938Z"* 
This gives me **12:35**.

When using `moment(Date.now()).format("DDMMYYYY_HHmm")` I get the current date with the hour I am expecting: *"26032020_1335"* 
This gives me **13:35**.

What am I missing here to get the correct date and time?
To be clear, i need a Date object. Not a string.

Comment: I assume your timezone is `UTC+1`?

Comment: Yes my current timezone is UTC+1.

Comment: `moment(Date.now()).valueOf() === moment().valueOf()`, by the way...

Comment: The Date object (which you could get by just running `new Date()`) is the current date and time, in the time zone of the browser, as reported to the browser by the OS you run it on. See [How do I get the current date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1531093/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey—Date objects are UTC, it's the *get* and *toString* methods that return local values.

Comment: `moment(Date.now()).toDate()` is just very inefficent way of doing `new Date()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `moment(Date.now()).toDate()`, I presume you logged that date to the console. When a date is logged to the console, it displays as an ISO 8601 date, which uses UTC time. So, it is the correct time, just in a different timezone. If you call `.toString` on the date you should see the correct time for your timezone.

Comment: I am actually displaying it on my webpage whilst debugging, but I guess it makes for the same output. You are right, using `.toString` actually displays the correct time. However when I send it to the backend trough an API-call, the date still has the wrong time.

Comment: If you parse the date, it'll automatically convert to the correct timezone. Remember, dates are really just a number and the timezone it displays as doesn't affect the value of that number.

Comment: "*When a date is logged to the console, it displays as an ISO 8601 date, which uses UTC*" depends on the console.