# Creating list of values and Convert the value Date format in 'yyyy-M-d'

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-platform

By using Mat-Date-Picker I am creating the date value
**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Select date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [formControl]="form.controls['Date']">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Typescript**

```
    ngOnInit() {
        const date = { Date: '' };
        this.form = this.fb.group({
        Date: this.formatDate(date.Date)
        });
    }
formatDate(date: Date) {
  return `${this.formattedDate.getFullYear()}-${this.formattedDate.getMonth()}-${this.formattedDate.getDate()}`;
}
```

Getting `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Date'`

After creating a list of values. In that list, I am getting the date format in datastore as Below.

```
{"Date":"2020-07-30T18:30:00.000Z"}
```

I want to display in datastore `2020-07-31`

How to format getting date in datastore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Date instance like this

```
var date = {"Date": "2020-07-30T18:30:00.000"}

var formattedDate = new Date(date.Date)

console.log(`${formattedDate.getFullYear()}-${formattedDate.getMonth()}-${formattedDate.getDate()}`) 
// output:  2020-6-30
```

For your case:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    date = { Date: "2020-07-30T18:30:00.000Z" }; // <- assume the date is here
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        Date: this.formatDate(date.Date)
    });
}

formatDate(date) {
 this.formattedDate = new Date(date);
  return `${this.formattedDate.getFullYear()}-${this.formattedDate.getMonth()}-${this.formattedDate.getDate()}`;
}
```

Comment: By using date instance you can create date, modify existing date, fetch date, year, time from it etc.

Comment: Here, In above updated typescript class form group there is Date Field. How we use date instance?

Comment: By using date instance you can create date, modify existing date, fetch date, year, time from it etc.

eg: to get present date: console.log(new Date()) // Fri Jul 31 2020 10:55:41 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

modify existing date then send that date to Date instance as parameter
eg: my DOB is 21 09 1968 and i want to get day from this then
console.log(new Date("21 09 1968").getDay()) // 1 here 1 means monday

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Comment: learn more about date instance by going through mdn and stackoverflow links, that will help you understand more

Comment: Getting Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Date' error in Date: this.formatDate(date.Date)

Comment: see my example now i've made changes according to your scenario

Comment: I can't find your example @Yerrapotu ManojKiran

Comment: use this 
formatDate(date) {
 this.formattedDate = new Date(date);
  return `${formattedDate.getFullYear()}-${formattedDate.getMonth()}-${formattedDate.getDate()}`;
}

Comment: Yeah i have tried same but getting result in console log Nan-Nan-Nan

Comment: sorry use this, formatDate(date) { this.formattedDate = new Date(date); return ${this.formattedDate.getFullYear()}-${this.formattedDate.getMonth()}-${this.formattedDate.getDate()}; }

Comment: yeah same like that but not getting. can we discuss in chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218966/discussion-between-yerrapotu-manojkiran-and-prasannakumar-chebrolu).

Comment: Hi, Manoj, While saving the date it getting wrong value