# My Django minutes being read reads as month?

Tags: javascript, html, django, datetime-format

Hi so I've been developing a countdown timer account, and I made a code like the following (following a tutorial):

```
{% for time in timer %}
   <p id="tm" style="margin-top:-8px;margin-bottom:20px;display:none;">{{time.time|date:"M d, Y H:m:s"}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I have set the timer in the clock widget to 03:50 but when I console.log via javascript

```
const timeLength = documents.getElementById('tm');
console.log(timeLength.textContent)
```

It prints 03:12, always been read as month instead of minutes.
But the minute is always set to be read as month,
[image]

And I am already sure that M (uppercase) supposed to represent month, and the m (lowercase) represents the minute, right?? Where did I go wrong? I have been stuck here for days, and from the research on google I have done, always said that M is month, and m is minute..
Thank you in advance.

Comment: create a date object like `let date = new Date()` in js. you can enter your django templatevalue and format it in the way you want it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript for further date reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And I am already sure that M (uppercase) supposed to represent month, and the m (lowercase) represents the minute, right??

**No**. The date specifier is similar to PHP's date formatter. As the [documentation section on the date format says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date):

| Format character | Description | Example Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `m` | Month, 2 digits with leading zeros. | `'01'` to `'12'` |
| (…) | (…) | (…) |
| `M` | Month, textual, 3 letters. | `'Jan'` |
| (…) | (…) | (…) |
| `i` | Minutes. | `'00'` to `'59'` |

You thus use `i` for minutes:

```
{{ time.time|date:"M d, Y H:i:s" }}
```