# Javascript Insert Date without leading zeros

Tags: javascript, date

I am absolutely new to Javascript. I am trying to get a certain format for a date I need inserted.
Essentially, I want it to look like mm/dd/yy but I do not want leading zeros when there is a single digit month or date. Is this possible? I tried the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript) but it gives me leading zeros and a four digit year.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You are on the right track, especially with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64269468/1871033). Read the linked documentation, you'll find [a lot of options described there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat). In your particular case you'd use `2-digit` for year and `numeric` for month and day.

Comment: Wonder if my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it does what you want:

```js
let today = new Date();
const day = String(today.getDate())
const month = String(today.getMonth() + 1); // January is counted as 0
let year = today.getFullYear();

year = `${year}`.split("").splice(2,3).join("")

today = `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
document.write(today);
```

Comment: `\`${today.getDate()}/${today.getMonth()+1}/${today.getFullYear()%100}\``

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at the top votes answer from the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript) you are looking at.

In the answer, they use `the padstart()` to insert `0` for single day.

> The padStart() method pads the current string with another string
> (multiple times, if needed) until the resulting string reaches the
> given length. The padding is applied from the start of the current
> string.

The simplest solution is to just remove the two `padStart` from that answer.

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate())
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
document.write(today);
```