# How to display proper time base on user timezone?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, momentjs

## Description:

I build this web app for my son as his newborn gift  last year. My wife & I are obsessed with it since. We use it extensively every day until now on our phones, tablets, laptops, TVs, and even our Samsung fridge (required only internet & browser). I will release this to **ALL** parents in the world ***soon**** for **FREE**. But now I want to allow my nephew & niece in `Texas` to use this dashboard/web app as a family test. I have to support diff timezone. Right now it only supports US ET which is where I live.

[image]

[image]

**JJ's Dashboard**

Desktop View (*Read-only*)

https://mybabies.app/baby/a4b7efe4-9c2f-4c48-b5b1-cc516a8f027f?code=N0Vk90

## Setup:

My config/app.php current set to `'timezone' => 'America/New_York',`
I use `moment.js` a lot in the front-end to display my entire date/time logic.

---

## I was thinking:

to take the input as `+2`, `+3`, and so on.... so I can render the time based on that. I know I have to take user timezone as input and store that into the database as : `+2, +3, ...` . I've done that. I can also query back what user set as well. I just don't know what to do with that TZ. I'm afraid that I will change my codes in tons of places..

**Is there a way to just detect user TZ just like we detect user dateTime? Should I consider that route instead ?**

## What are the proper steps I should take?

Comment: From my experience the browser is the most likely one to have an accurate knowledge of the user's timezone so I think you could leverage moment.js to take the user's current timezone into account when formatting

Comment: You can get user time zone in JavaScript using Web Browser Timezone offset then pass that to PHP on the back-end to save to your Database. In JavaScript you could do var userTz = new Date().getTimezoneOffset(); then find a way of posting userTz back to PHP on the back-end. See documentation here https://usefulangle.com/post/31/detect-user-browser-timezone-name-in-php

Comment: @apokryfos I like your suggestion because it seems to be the least work possible, just use the moment to display the updated time based on the user timezone, and leave the current time that query from the database as is... only works need to be done in the front-end. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @Joseph Thanks for your answer, I don't mind passing the userTz to the database, but I'm wondering if maybe we don't have to modify any back-end codes so less test for me after that. There is so many timestamps in the back-end codes, and the app also use live web-socket too when users `pressed to log` ... I'm afraid that this will be a night-more for testing... Have you reviewed apokryfos's comment? What is your thought on that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the current date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Although it's still in proposal stage you might want to familiarize yourself with the upcoming Temporal API that will eventually replace js Date

Answer (score 0):

I think very optimistically... I got a timezone to work on my app now. **Huge** thanks to **all** the comments from everyone above, without you guys, I will never found the best working solution for my situation with such minimum changes.

## Front-end

First, I added 2 lines of code, I grab the client timezone

```
 const timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone; <<< ADDED : Line #1
```

Since I have already made an ajax on log pressed anyway, I just need to one more field to the server

```
var data    = {};
data.tz     = timezone; <<< ADDED : Line #2
```

## Back-end

Second, with 5 lines of code, I can access what I sent from FE like so to overwrite the created_at time.

```
$tz     = $inputs['tz']; <<< ADDED : Line #3 

$clientDate = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($tz) ); <<< ADDED : Line #4 
$clientTimestamp = $clientDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); <<< ADDED : Line #5 

$log             = new BabyLog;
$log->type       = $type;
$log->created_at = $clientTimestamp; <<< ADDED : Line #6 
$log->updated_at = $clientTimestamp; <<< ADDED : Line #7 
$log->save();
```

## Now

My database stored the right timestamp() based on my client device/browser.

No other codes needed, it just works.

---

## Test

I changed the Date & Time on my iPhone from `Chicago` to  `New York` back and forth. I pressed log, it saved, and I noticed my front-end displayed the accurate time based on my client timezone now.

[image]

## I hope

this post helps someone like me that wants to make their web-app work globally with minimal code changes. *To be very specific* in `7` lines of codes.